# Batch executed by Python script is acting like it is in the script's folder

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, jar

I run the batch(it is in different folder than the python script) the using following line of code:

```
subprocess.Popen("the_bat.bat", creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

The job of the batch is to launch a .jar(same directory as batch) which creates folders and files in it's directory, but when run by the python script the jar starts doing it's job in the script's folder.
Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

Comment: Batch file is the `%0` parameter. `Echo %~dp0` will print the batch file's folder. See `call /?`.

Comment: The directory a program is loaded from is not the same as the current directory.  You can set the current working directory of the child process by the `cwd` parameter to `Popen`.

Comment: use code formatting next time

Comment: Do as @Noodles suggests. Your batch script shouldn't depend on the working directory to find resources relative to itself. If it needs to set the working directory relative to itself before running another program, then it should `pushd %~dp0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the bash script is executed in Python's working directory, which makes the bash script's working directory the same one as Python's. You can fix this by passing a current working directory to the `subprocess.Popen`.

`subprocess.Popen(r'your script', cwd=r'd:\the\working\directory\you\want\or\root')`